# Cisco's AnyConnect to use wired interface

Tags: wifi, mac-mini, vpn, sharing, ethernet

I have a Mac with wired and wifi network interfaces. I use it as a wireless access point (sharing ethernet via access point). When I connect AnyConnect to a vpn, wifi is disabled and other devices at home fail to use internet. May I restrict AnyConnect to use only wired connection?